# Update using LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How can I update a record against specific id in LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 56):

LINQ is a query tool (Q = Query) - so there is no magic LINQ way to update just the single row, except through the (object-oriented) data-context (in the case of LINQ-to-SQL). To update data, you need to fetch it out, update the record, and submit the changes:

```
using(var ctx = new FooContext()) {
    var obj = ctx.Bars.Single(x=>x.Id == id);
    obj.SomeProp = 123;
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Or write an SP that does the same in TSQL, and expose the SP through the data-context:

```
using(var ctx = new FooContext()) {
    ctx.UpdateBar(id, 123);
}
```

Comment: @Mathieu - do you propose that it guesses values for the 200 properties? they need to come from somewhere...

Comment: Sorry, I had something in mind that is not shown here, my bad.

Answer (score 5):

In the absence of more detailed info:

```
using(var dbContext = new dbDataContext())
{
    var data = dbContext.SomeTable.SingleOrDefault(row => row.id == requiredId);
    if(data != null)
    {
        data.SomeField = newValue;
    }
    dbContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: That won't compile; Where(pred) will return an IQueryable<SomeType>, not a SomeType

Comment: This worked for me where the top answer (currently) did not. +1 because this is a more simply coded easy to understand / modify example

Answer (score 2):

```
AdventureWorksDataContext db = new AdventureWorksDataContext();
db.Log = Console.Out;

// Get hte first customer record
Customer c = from cust in db.Customers select cust where id = 5;
Console.WriteLine(c.CustomerType);
c.CustomerType = 'I';
db.SubmitChanges(); // Save the changes away
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();

 FamilyDetail fd = dc.FamilyDetails.Single(p => p.UserId == 1);

 fd.FatherName=txtFatherName.Text;
        fd.FatherMobile=txtMobile.Text;
        fd.FatherOccupation=txtFatherOccu.Text;
        fd.MotherName=txtMotherName.Text;
        fd.MotherOccupation=txtMotherOccu.Text;
        fd.Phone=txtPhoneNo.Text;
        fd.Address=txtAddress.Text;
        fd.GuardianName=txtGardianName.Text;

        dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround a week ago. You can use direct commands with "`ExecuteCommand`":

```
MDataContext dc = new MDataContext();
var flag = (from f in dc.Flags
                   where f.Code == Code
                   select f).First();
_refresh = Convert.ToBoolean(flagRefresh.Value);
if (_refresh)
{
    dc.ExecuteCommand("update Flags set value = 0 where code = {0}", Code);
}
```

In the `ExecuteCommand` statement, you can send the query directly, with the value for the specific record you want to update.

> value = 0    --> 0 is the new value for the record;
>
> code = {0}   --> is the field where you will send the filter value;
>
> Code         --> is the new value for the field;

I hope this reference helps.

Comment: Why use ExecuteCommand to update!!?
Seems a little strange to do that when you can simply update the object and call SubmitChanges.