# Linq SQL update error: cannot resolve symbol

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I try to make update in SQL db and get error

Use official documentation from  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399339.aspx

```
var query =
from ord in db.Orders
where ord.OrderID == 11000
select ord;

foreach (Order ord in query)
{
ord.ShipName = "Mariner";
ord.ShipVia = 2;
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

And also try from [Update using LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909960/update-using-linq)

```
using(var ctx = new FooContext()) {
var obj = ctx.Bars.Single(x=>x.Id == 1100);
obj.SomeProp = 123;
ctx.SubmitChanges();
}}
```

Why is an error ?

```
ord.ShipName
Cannot resolve symbol 'ShipName'


var obj = ctx.Bars.Single(x=>x.Id == id);

Cannot resolve symbol 'Id'
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve symbol` would indicate that the property name isn't found as expected.  Can you post how you have the Order and Bar object properties declared?

Comment: Did you make an update to the table in dbml file, maybe that what causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add public modifier to your properties Id and ShipName

```
public class Bar
{
 public int Id
 {
   get;
   set;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not declare your variable before attempting to use it, or you misspelled it.
Another possibility is that the variable is in the wrong scope so it can't be reached.